# jQuery ajax call returning double results

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call in jQuery loading some elements into a div.

The call works, but for some reason is returning a duplicated response. The call should return two elements, but I get 4 (the 2 correct items, duplicated once).

Here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('feed/editor/2'); ?>",
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#feed-nav').after('<div class="loading"></div>', function(){
            $("#feeditems").fadeOut();
        });
    },
    success: function(html){
        $('#feed .loading').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $("#feeditems").append(html).slideDown('slow');
        });
    }
});

return false;
```

I can see no reason why this might be happening!?

**UPDATE**

I modified the success function to the code below which appears to have fixed it, although I don't really understand why.

```
success: function(html){
    $('#feed .loading').fadeOut();
    $("#feeditems").append(html).slideDown()
}
```

Comment: What do you see happening in firebug? Does the call really return data for only 2 elements?

Comment: From the code you posted, neither can I - what is `feed/editor/2` returning. From your code it would seem like your server is returning four elements, rather than the JS doubling it up?

Comment: In addition to using Firebug to see what the call is returning, it's also worth checking if the call is happening twice -- if the ajax call is triggered by an event handler, you may have bound the handler twice or some such; this is fairly common, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536660/jquery-click-event-handler-is-called-twice-for-a-checkbox

Comment: Just check with Firebug and it is definitely returning only 2 items.

Comment: The ajax call is just in the main onready jquery code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is the the selector you are using in the `success` callback, `$('#feed .loading')` is matching two elements and thus calls `$("#feeditems").append(html).slideDown('slow');` twice.  If your markup contains an element with the `loading` class on page load, the `beforeSend` callback is also adding a `div` with a `loading` class.  So you will either need to come up with a different selector in the `success` callback or not have multiple div's with the `loading` class.

Here I reproduce the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/2PR4V/2/

You can add this line of code to your `success` callback to see how many elements match:

```
console.log($('#feed .loading').size());
```

I fix the issue here by using a more specific selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/2PR4V/3/

Comment: Wow, you are absoluley correct. I had added another .loading div to see while I modified my css and this was exactly the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I used my cross-domain clairvoyance skills to grab your markup!

Comment: hah i was having a problem with appending content... it was getting the doubled because i had the same class name in another place. fixed it now :D thanks for your answer on this post