# jquery event handler calls the function twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, event-bubbling

When the a-tag with the class "like" is clicked the event handler calls the function twice.
I tried all hints of an [event bubbling post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536660/jquery-click-event-handler-is-called-twice-for-a-checkbox), but they didn't work or were not me case.

```
$('.like').live('click', function(){
    $.get($(this).attr('rel'), function(data)
    {
      $('.like').html(data);
    });
    return false;
 });
```

Maybe you have some more possible solutions for me?

Comment: Do you have a `.like` element nested inside another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try this?:

```
$('.like').die().live('click', function(){
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I had many sleepless nights because of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything works as supposed (take a look at the console):

http://jsfiddle.net/KU82w/1/

Can you provide the piece of HTML that your link is in?