# Trigger event click is executing multiple times using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `trigger('click')` while using the file upload in jQuery. I am providing my code below.

```
$(document).on('click', '.browse', function(){
   var file = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.file');
   file.trigger('click');
   console.log('header');
 })
```

My html part is given below.

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<input type="file" name="logoimage" id="logoimage" ng-model= "form.logoimage" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedImage(this);" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" class="file">
<div class="input-group col-xs-12">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Upload Logo" name="setlogoimage" id="setlogoimage" ng-model="setlogoimage">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="browse btn btn-primary" type="button">Upload File</button></span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

If I am clicking on file input the above function is executing 3/2 times and I can know it from the console messages. At one time click `header` is coming 3 times as result I have to click on open button after selecting file from discs also 3 times. Here I need to execute at once at one time click.

Comment: This is because you bind multiple click events.

Comment: You want to prevent event propagation after triggering a click on the file

Comment: Can you just help me to do this for this scenario ?

Comment: @Satpal : Yes, there are many `input type=file` in a single page whose class name is `.file` but its working sometimes and max times this scenarioa.

Comment: @Satpal : when I am checking the length its give the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Comment: @Satpal : I shared the html part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161529/discussion-between-satya-and-satpal).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery click event handler is called twice for a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536660/jquery-click-event-handler-is-called-twice-for-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

As your click event is getting binded multiple times you can use `off('click')`

```
$('.browse').off('click').on('click', function(){
  var file = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.file');
  file.trigger('click');
  console.log('header');
});
```

Comment: I did as per you but other click events are blocking while I am using this.

Comment: Can you please try the above-edited changes as now you will bind the click event on the `browser` class thus the other events wont get effected

Comment: I did as per you but the file browsing is not working at all.